# How to add additional menu items in Android app?

Tags: android, menu

I already have action bar with 4 menu items with image on my application screen. I want to add few more items but not in the action bar but these new items should be displayed when user click on "Menu" button on phone.

I have below property in `manifest.xml`:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Inside activity, I have below code.

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Also, I am overriding, onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu) for displaying action bar items.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your menu xml add

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

for each item that you want in the button and they will be added to your overflow menu or menu button